# Problem when I want to access a component from an external link vue router

Tags: vue-router

I need to recover the password of the users via email, the problem is that when I pass a link via email for example http://my-domain/recovery-password/token, it always redirects me to my login component (http://my-domain/login), what I need is go directly to my recovery-password component. I'm a little new in vue and I don't know what I need to change, this is my code in the router:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/check-balance',
    name: 'check-balance',
    component: CheckBalanceComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/check-payment',
    name: 'check-payment',
    component: CheckPaymentsComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/payment-disabled',
    name: 'payment-disabled',
    component: DisabledMakePaymentComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/handle-payment',
    name: 'handle-payment',
    component: HandlePaymentsComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/handle-report',
    name: 'handle-report',
    component: HandleReportsComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/user-profile',
    name: 'user-profile',
    component: UserProfileComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    meta: {
      free: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/recover-link', 
    name: 'recover-link',
    component: RecoverLinkComponent,
    meta: {
      free: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/recover-password', 
    name: 'recover-password',
    component: RecoverPasswordComponent,    
    meta: {
      free: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/help',
    name: 'help',
    component: HelpComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.free)){
    next()
  } else if(store.state.user && store.state.user.user_type == 1){
    next()
  // } else if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.fuera)){
  //   next({
  //     name: 'recover-password'
  //   })  
  } else {
    next({
      name: 'login'
    })
  }
})

export default router
```

I would appreciate your help because I have been standing for a long time without finding a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Vue looks through all the routes to find which one has `free` prop as part of its meta object.

And it always find `Login` route first before it ever gets to `recover-password` route - its reading top to bottom in the Routes Array.

So, try putting `recover-password` route before login route like so:

```js
  {
    path: '/recover-password', 
    name: 'recover-password',
    component: RecoverPasswordComponent,    
    meta: {
      free: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    meta: {
      free: 1
    }
  }
```

However, you may start encountering that recover component renders in places where you may need login component.

So, the best way to solve this whole issue is by giving a different `free` value to both routes and then check for that value in your `beforeEach` hook.

Comment: I try:     

 `{
    path: '/recover-password', 
    name: 'recover-password',
    component: RecoverPasswordComponent,    
    meta: {
      other: 1
    }
  }`

  And in the hook

  `if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.other)){
    next()
  } 
  `

  But it does not work

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to actually do the navigation..

Comment: i answer my own question with the code changes, that you suggested to me, please check above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@nishkaush

This is my vue router code with the changes you suggested to me:

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/check-balance',
    name: 'check-balance',
    component: CheckBalanceComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/check-payment',
    name: 'check-payment',
    component: CheckPaymentsComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/payment-disabled',
    name: 'payment-disabled',
    component: DisabledMakePaymentComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/handle-payment',
    name: 'handle-payment',
    component: HandlePaymentsComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/handle-report',
    name: 'handle-report',
    component: HandleReportsComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/user-profile',
    name: 'user-profile',
    component: UserProfileComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  }, 
  {
    path: '/recover-password', 
    name: 'recover-password',
    component: RecoverPasswordComponent,    
    meta: {
      other: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/recover-link', 
    name: 'recover-link',
    component: RecoverLinkComponent,
    meta: {
      free: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    params: {
      recovery_email: 'email'
    },
    meta: {
      free: 1
    }
  },
  
  {
    path: '/help',
    name: 'help',
    component: HelpComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.free)){
    next()
  }  
  else if(store.state.user && store.state.user.user_type == 1){
    next()
  }
  
  /*This is where I have to call my recover-password component, 
  from an external link without redirecting to the login*/
  else if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.other)){
    next()
  }
  else {
    next({
      name: 'login'
    })
  }
})

export default router
```